# Adding a bounce effect using CSS animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm playing round with CSS animation by trying to replicate the following new google ads logo - [example](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1309&bih=638&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=4la3W9mVBIz2vgTJ-7KADQ&q=google%20ads%20logo&oq=google%20ads%20logo&gs_l=img.3..0l8j0i7i30k1l2.10396.11178.0.11441.2.2.0.0.0.0.378.378.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..1.1.377....0.Zr1qLSnzl9Y#imgrc=vHytBDBbp5qHuM).

What is the best way to add the bounce effect on the green ball?

My current animation:

```
@keyframes greenblock {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 45px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

My code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/as7zrp9e/6/)):

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative
}

.blue-shape {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #4285F4;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 45px;
  animation: blueblock 2s forwards;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.yellow-shape {
  position: absolute;
  left: 122px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #FBBC04;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 45px;
  animation: yellowblock 2s forwards;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.green-ball {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #34A853;
  animation: greenblock 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes blueblock {
  0% {
    height: 45px;
  }
  25% {
    height: 140px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    height: 140px;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
}

@keyframes yellowblock {
  0% {
    height: 45px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    height: 140px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
  100% {
    height: 140px;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    opacity: 100;
    left: 122px;
  }
}

@keyframes greenblock {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 45px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="yellow-shape">
    <div class="green-ball">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blue-shape">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with this animation

```
animation: greenblock .6s ease-in-out .5s forwards;
```

and this set of keyframes

```
@keyframes greenblock {
   0% {  top: 0px; }
   75% {  top: calc(100% - 55px); }
   50%, 100% { top: calc(100% - 45px); }
}
```

> [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnoams40/)

---

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative
}

.blue-shape {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #4285F4;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 45px;
  animation: blueblock 2s forwards;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.yellow-shape {
  position: absolute;
  left: 122px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #FBBC04;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 45px;
  animation: yellowblock 2s forwards;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.green-ball {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: #34A853;
  animation: greenblock .6s ease-in-out .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes blueblock {
  0% {
    height: 45px;
  }
  25% {
    height: 140px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    height: 140px;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
}

@keyframes yellowblock {
  0% {
    height: 45px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    height: 140px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
  100% {
    height: 140px;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    opacity: 100;
    left: 122px;
  }
}

@keyframes greenblock {
   0% {  top: 0px; }
   75% {  top: calc(100% - 55px); }
   50%, 100% { top: calc(100% - 45px); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="yellow-shape">
    <div class="green-ball">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blue-shape">

  </div>
</div>
```